# SIGBUS while doing memcpy from mmap ed buffer which is in RAM as identified by mincore

Tags: linux, mmap, memcpy, sigbus

I am mmapping a block as:

`mapAddr = mmap((void*) 0, curMapSize, PROT_NONE, MAP_LOCKED|MAP_SHARED, fd, curMapOffset);`

if this does not fail `(mapAddr != MAP_FAILED)` I query mincore as:

`err = mincore((char*) mapAddr, pageSize, &mincoreRet);`

to find out whether it is in RAM. In case it is in RAM (err == 0 && mincoreRet & 0x01) I mmap it again for reading as:

`copyAddr = mmap((void*) 0, curMapSize, PROT_READ, MAP_LOCKED|MAP_SHARED, fd, curMapOffset);`

and then I try to copy it out to my buffer as:

`memcpy(data, copyAddr, pageSize);`

everything works fine except in the last memcpy once in a while I get SIGBUS. When I check **/proc/ /smaps** at the time of the failure I notice that it has Rss as well as Locked fields as 0 as listed below:

```
7f4a4c118000-7f4a4c119000 r--s 00326000 00:17 6                          <file name>

Size:                  4 kB

Rss:                   0 kB

Pss:                   0 kB

Shared_Clean:          0 kB

Shared_Dirty:          0 kB

Private_Clean:         0 kB

Private_Dirty:         0 kB

Referenced:            0 kB

Anonymous:             0 kB

AnonHugePages:         0 kB

Swap:                  0 kB

KernelPageSize:        4 kB

MMUPageSize:           4 kB

Locked:                0 kB
```

Any thoughts? This is happening on ubuntu 12.0.4 with kernel version 3.5.0-36.

Comment: I'm assuming you're on x86?